# How do I resolve force close error upon onActivityResult() call?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I have an application that takes a picture using an intent.
Here is my main activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image, return media file
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}
```

And this is my onActivityResult method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Log.d("onActivityResult",data.getData().toString());
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            Log.d("Image", photo.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

In the manifest I requested permission to

1. read and write
2. uses-feature camera.

The application runs, allows you to take a picture but once you accept the picture I get a force close error and I'm not sure why. I used this link as guidance and most of the code I got off the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and I have browsed stackoverflow for similar problems, this link was the closest application I could find [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

I still get a force close (after taking a picture, it doesn't return to the application).
Any help would be much appreciated.

The entire class is as follows

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private Uri fileUri;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private ImageView imageView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });



}

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DecodeM");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

}

logcat error:

```
06-13 09:29:04.123: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed:java.net.SocketException:     Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 09:34:04.170: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 09:39:04.224: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 09:44:04.275: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 09:49:04.282: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 09:54:04.297: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 09:59:04.336: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:04:04.380: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:09:04.382: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:14:04.413: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:19:04.467: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:22:04.880: DEBUG/dalvikvm(209): GC_CONCURRENT freed 496K, 52% free 2981K/6151K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 7ms+11ms
06-13 10:24:04.521: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:29:04.584: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:34:04.601: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:39:04.629: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:44:04.640: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:49:04.697: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:54:04.720: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 10:59:04.746: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:04:04.757: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:09:04.786: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:14:04.795: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:19:04.859: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:22:00.270: DEBUG/dalvikvm(74): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1188K, 59% free 4352K/10375K, external 3520K/3903K, paused 8ms+11ms
06-13 11:24:04.906: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:29:04.960: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:34:04.962: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:35:46.359: INFO/jdwp(204): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
06-13 11:35:46.482: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.490: DEBUG/dalvikvm(338): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.550: DEBUG/dalvikvm(74): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.550: DEBUG/dalvikvm(320): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.560: DEBUG/dalvikvm(265): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.560: DEBUG/dalvikvm(209): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.641: INFO/jdwp(307): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
06-13 11:35:46.641: DEBUG/dalvikvm(307): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:46.831: DEBUG/dalvikvm(204): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.400: INFO/jdwp(405): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
06-13 11:35:47.419: DEBUG/dalvikvm(439): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.459: DEBUG/dalvikvm(364): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.489: DEBUG/dalvikvm(389): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.489: DEBUG/dalvikvm(416): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.489: DEBUG/dalvikvm(405): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.489: INFO/jdwp(285): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
06-13 11:35:47.512: DEBUG/dalvikvm(285): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:47.632: DEBUG/dalvikvm(350): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:35:51.260: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(586): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-13 11:35:51.260: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(586): CheckJNI is ON
06-13 11:35:54.200: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(586): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-13 11:35:54.680: DEBUG/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 54% free 2538K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 175ms
06-13 11:35:54.700: WARN/ActivityManager(74): No content provider found for:
06-13 11:35:54.850: WARN/ActivityManager(74): No content provider found for:
06-13 11:35:54.930: DEBUG/PackageParser(74): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl585229931.tmp
06-13 11:35:55.383: INFO/PackageManager(74): Removing non-system package:com.decode.app1
06-13 11:35:55.390: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Force stopping package com.decode.app1 uid=10035
06-13 11:35:56.261: DEBUG/PackageManager(74): Scanning package com.decode.app1
06-13 11:35:56.270: INFO/PackageManager(74): Package com.decode.app1 codePath changed from /data/app/com.decode.app1-1.apk to /data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
06-13 11:35:56.280: INFO/PackageManager(74): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk
06-13 11:35:56.372: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk' ---
06-13 11:35:57.260: DEBUG/dalvikvm(595): DexOpt: load 135ms, verify+opt 296ms
06-13 11:35:57.313: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk' (success) ---
06-13 11:35:57.350: WARN/PackageManager(74): Code path for pkg : com.decode.app1 changing from /data/app/com.decode.app1-1.apk to /data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk
06-13 11:35:57.350: WARN/PackageManager(74): Resource path for pkg : com.decode.app1 changing from /data/app/com.decode.app1-1.apk to /data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk
06-13 11:35:57.360: DEBUG/PackageManager(74): Activities: com.decode.app1.MyActivity
06-13 11:35:57.430: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Force stopping package com.decode.app1 uid=10035
06-13 11:35:58.330: INFO/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.decode.app1-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.decode.app1-2.apk@classes.dex
06-13 11:35:58.363: DEBUG/PackageManager(74): New package installed in /data/app/com.decode.app1-2.apk
06-13 11:35:58.389: WARN/PackageManager(74): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package com.decode.app1
06-13 11:35:59.420: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Force stopping package com.decode.app1 uid=10035
06-13 11:35:59.780: DEBUG/dalvikvm(74): GC_EXPLICIT freed 607K, 59% free 4273K/10375K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 331ms
06-13 11:36:00.150: DEBUG/dalvikvm(265): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 50% free 2960K/5895K, external 5863K/6816K, paused 269ms
06-13 11:36:00.770: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): GC_EXPLICIT freed 142K, 53% free 2757K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 418ms
06-13 11:36:01.433: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(74): no available voice recognition services found
06-13 11:36:02.724: DEBUG/dalvikvm(74): GC_EXPLICIT freed 191K, 59% free 4255K/10375K, external 3511K/3903K, paused 556ms
06-13 11:36:03.570: INFO/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.decode.app1-1.apk@classes.dex
06-13 11:36:03.641: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(586): Shutting down VM
06-13 11:36:03.710: INFO/AndroidRuntime(586): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-13 11:36:03.740: DEBUG/dalvikvm(586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 294K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+16ms
06-13 11:36:03.760: DEBUG/dalvikvm(586): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:36:06.312: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(598): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
06-13 11:36:06.312: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(598): CheckJNI is ON
06-13 11:36:10.020: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(598): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-13 11:36:10.170: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.decode.app1/.MyActivity } from pid 598
06-13 11:36:10.490: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(598): Shutting down VM
06-13 11:36:10.590: INFO/AndroidRuntime(598): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #4' failed
06-13 11:36:10.810: DEBUG/dalvikvm(598): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+36ms
06-13 11:36:10.810: DEBUG/jdwp(598): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
06-13 11:36:10.810: DEBUG/dalvikvm(598): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 11:36:11.545: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Start proc com.decode.app1 for activity com.decode.app1/.MyActivity: pid=609 uid=10035 gids={1015}
06-13 11:36:16.250: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Displayed com.decode.app1/.MyActivity: +4s961ms
06-13 11:36:17.993: DEBUG/dalvikvm(307): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2538K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 10600ms
06-13 11:36:21.610: DEBUG/dalvikvm(405): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 55% free 2591K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 201ms
06-13 11:36:26.761: DEBUG/dalvikvm(265): GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 50% free 2955K/5895K, external 5892K/6816K, paused 277ms
06-13 11:36:31.760: DEBUG/dalvikvm(439): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 55% free 2531K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 230ms
06-13 11:39:05.040: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:39:18.269: DEBUG/MyCameraApp(609): failed to create directory
06-13 11:39:18.289: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(609): Shutting down VM
06-13 11:39:18.289: WARN/dalvikvm(609): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-13 11:39:18.339: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: file
    at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:397)
    at com.decode.app1.MyActivity.getOutputMediaFileUri(MyActivity.java:55)
    at com.decode.app1.MyActivity.access$100(MyActivity.java:22)
    at com.decode.app1.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-13 11:39:18.389: WARN/ActivityManager(74): Force finishing activity com.decode.app1/.MyActivity
06-13 11:39:19.009: WARN/ActivityManager(74): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{405316b0 com.decode.app1/.MyActivity}
06-13 11:39:24.770: INFO/Process(609): Sending signal. PID: 609 SIG: 9
06-13 11:39:24.940: ERROR/InputDispatcher(74): channel '4096a3e0 com.decode.app1/com.decode.app1.MyActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
06-13 11:39:24.940: ERROR/InputDispatcher(74): channel '4096a3e0 com.decode.app1/com.decode.app1.MyActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-13 11:39:24.950: INFO/ActivityManager(74): Process com.decode.app1 (pid 609) has died.
06-13 11:39:25.175: INFO/WindowManager(74): WINDOW DIED Window{4096a3e0 com.decode.app1/com.decode.app1.MyActivity paused=false}
06-13 11:39:25.310: WARN/WindowManager(74): Failed looking up window
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@406366a0 does not exist
    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8174)
    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8165)
    at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowManagerService.java:7024)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:381)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-13 11:39:25.310: INFO/WindowManager(74): WIN DEATH: null
06-13 11:39:25.790: WARN/InputManagerService(74): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 609 uid 10035
06-13 11:39:32.667: WARN/ActivityManager(74): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{405316b0 com.decode.app1/.MyActivity}
06-13 11:44:05.170: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:49:05.180: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:49:46.323: INFO/dalvikvm(320): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
06-13 11:54:05.250: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 11:59:05.271: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-13 12:04:05.340: DEBUG/SntpClient(74): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: post your logcat that find out what is error occure

Comment: i think u r not able to get the path of captured image uri, so it may give nullpointer exception. please check or provide logcat to review problem

Comment: @sunil ERROR/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException: file
        at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:397)
        at com.decode.app1.MyActivity.getOutputMediaFileUri(MyActivity.java:55)
        at com.decode.app1.MyActivity.access$100(MyActivity.java:22)
        at com.decode.app1.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:42)

Comment: @abhishesh looks like you're right about the nullpointer exception. Any idea on how to resolve it? I've tried both solutions below with no luck

Comment: Stop discussing, give the logcat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function

```
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
```

just assumes you're getting a non-null value from `getOutputMediaFile`. Which isn't true: there are several ways to get null values from it. And that causes an exception (at least the [Uri.fromFile(File file) documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29) says so.

So, you could change it to

```
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    File fileToReturn =  getOutputMediaFile(type);
    return  fileToReturn!=null?Uri.fromFile(fileToReturn):  
    null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call activity result like that and get the path of the image

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

and call this way

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        try {

                   if ( resultData != null) {

                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToLast();

                String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath );
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage );

            }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
```

Comment: When testing, this solution gets rid of the error but the image doesn't get placed into the imageVeiw. Instead it selects a random image from the gallery or displays no image at all. And if the file location doesn't exist, it creates the file location and force closes. But if the file location does exist, no errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Instend of this:

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Use `fileUri` variable value in OnActivityResult.